# Simplifying Trig Identities

Tags: trigonometry

I need to factor and simplify $\cos(x)^4\sec(x)^2\cos(x)^2\tan(x)^4$.
So far I know that $\cos(x)^4$ will cancel out because $\tan(x)^4$ becomes $(\sin(x)^4/\cos(x)^4)$ which leaves me with $\sec(x)^2\cos(x)^2\sin(x)^4$.

I want to know if I'm on the right track or I did something wrong? 
If I am, can I cancel $\cos(x)^2$ because $\sec(x)^2$ can become $1/\cos(x)^2$?

But then I'm left with $\sin(x)^4$ and I want to know if that's factorizable?

Comment: You are correct ... $\sin ^4 x$ it is

Answer (score 1):

As Mark said, your answer is correct; all of your steps are perfectly logical. $\sin^4(x)$ is likely the simplest way you could express the answer. If you wanted to, you could write it as $\left(1-\cos^2(x)\right)^2$ (from the identity $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$), but aside from that, I think $\sin^4(x)$ is perfectly fine.